# How to validate an XML file with a schema in memory with .NET?

Tags: .net, xsd

Is it possible to validate an XML file using an XSD loaded at runtime from embedded application resources instead of using a physical file, with .NET (Framework 3.5)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `XmlSchemaCollection.Add(string, XmlReader)`:

```
string file = "Assembly.Namespace.FileName.ext";
XmlSchemaCollection xsc = new XmlSchemaCollection();
xsc.Add(null, new XmlTextReader(
    this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(file)));
```

Comment: thank you, I figured out how to implement the "... your resource stream here..." and now it works

Comment: how can I improve this answer, marco?

Comment: I thinks is ok, but probably you can describe or add a link how to retrieve an embedded resource file from an assembly

Answer (score 2):

Here's mine:

```
public static bool IsValid(XElement element, params string[] schemas)
{
    XmlSchemaSet xsd = new XmlSchemaSet();
    XmlReader xr = null;
    foreach (string s in schemas)
    { 
        xr = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s)));
        xsd.Add(null, xr);
    }
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(element);
    var errored = false;
    doc.Validate(xsd, (o, e) => errored = true);
    return !errored;
}
```

And you can use it by:

```
var xe = XElement.Parse(myXmlString); //by memory; may be wrong
var result = IsValid(xe, MyApp.Properties.Resources.MyEmbeddedXSD);
```

This isn't a guarantee that this is 100%; its just a good starting point for you.  XSD validation isn't something I'm completely up on...

Answer (score 1):

Check out how it is done in Winter4NET. The full source code [is here](http://code.google.com/p/nicnet/source/browse/trunk/src/NI.Winter/XmlComponentsConfig.cs#89). The essential code excerpt:

```
Stream GetXsdStream() {
    string name = this.GetType().Namespace + ".ComponentsConfigSchema.xsd";
    return Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream( name ); 
}

...

XmlSchema schema = XmlSchema.Read( GetXsdStream(), null);
xmlDoc.Schemas.Add( schema );
xmlDoc.Validate(new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationCallBack));
```